# Replace the <a> text of a ul in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace the  a  text of a  ul  list using jQuery, but I am running into to issues. First the code only works if I click  'BTI' , and I need it to work right after the page opens, already tried .one and  .ready  . And second the code only replaces the text  'BTI'  and it needs to do  'GIA'  as well.

**HTML :**

```
<ul id="addition_membership_type-menu" class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-selectmenu-menu-dropdown ui-corner-bottom w230 ui-selectmenu-open" aria-labelledby="addition_membership_type-button" role="listbox" aria-hidden="false" style="z-index: 9999; width: 230px; height: 250px; top: 1403.8px; left: 577px;" aria-disabled="false" aria-activedescendant="ui-selectmenu-item-517">

    <li class="hide-from-ui-list" role="presentation">
        <a id="" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1" href="#">--- Please select ---</a>
    </li>
    <li class="" role="presentation"> 
        <a aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1" href="#">BTI</a>
    </li>
    <li class="" role="presentation">
        <a aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1" href="#">GIA</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$('#addition_membership_type-menu li a').click(function(){

    $(this).text(function(index, text) {
        return text.replace('BTI', 'Baltic Miles');
        return text.replace('GIA', 'G airline');
    });

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is happening as you are attaching a click event to anchor. Do it on document ready

Comment: You have two return statements. It will only do the first, not the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - You were using click event, so it would only execute on click. Change it to run on dom ready (`$(function(){});`)

2 - It was running only on the clicked element, you must iterate through all elements (`.each`)

3 - You were using two return statements, so the second one was never reached. Chaining the `.replace` methods is a possible solution is your case.

```
$(function(){
    $('#addition_membership_type-menu li a').each(function(){
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace('BTI', 'Baltic Miles').replace('GIA', 'G airline'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Why add the jQuery enclousure?If you want to immediately invoke the function just use the IIFE standard: `(function(){ your code here })();`

Comment: @Narayon those are not the same thing. `$(function(){ })` is executed `onDomReady`, while IIFE executes immediately. This means, if the script is added in the header, IIFE will run before the elements are available, thus running on an empty set.

Comment: You're right. Never used that syntax, only `$(document).ready();`. Nice shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

A function can only have one return statement. After you hit one return statement, the code leaves that function and stops executing. If you want it to do multiple things, try

```
text.replace('BTI', 'Baltic Miles');
text.replace('GIA', 'G airline');
```

You don't need to return a value unless you're going to use that value (e.g. a function that adds two to an input would return 2 + input so you can use it later).

Also, consider using `window.onload = function ...` to get it to execute immediately.

your end code might look something like this:

```
window.onload = function(index, text) {
$('#addition_membership_type-menu li a').replace('BTI', 'Baltic Miles');
$('#addition_membership_type-menu li a').replace('GIA', 'G airline');
});
```

Comment: A function can return more than one thing, but it can only have one return statement (unless you have conditions). And in this case, it needs to return something.

Comment: I edited for clarity about the return statement, thank you.